# WinForms, C# Diffenrent Control Locations in RunningMode than Editor

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have copied an existing (and working) Form, replaced the Image and did some configurations in Code (But not really Control-Location-Related).
My Form in the Editor Looks like this (how it should)

Editor:
[image: Editor]

I have a Panel01 which includes every Control.
Inside Panel01 is a MenuStrip AND Panel02.
Panel 02 includes every Control:
- Textboxes
- Checkboxes
- Dates
- And the Pictue (which is marked in Pink) 998x1426 Pixel

When starting the Program and Opening the Form, the Picture moves downwards, some Controls do the same. However, some controls stay where i placed them in Editor.

This is how it Looks like:

Running Program

[image: Running Program]

I have also tried deleting the Image but the Controls stay at their wrong Locations.
The Control.Location.Y is equal both in Editor and Running.

How do I correct my mistake? What exactly is my mistake?
I really want to have the Form in Running Program look like in Editor.

I attach some (hopefully) Screenshots as well.

If anybody can help me I would be really grateful (I'm already becoming crazy)…

Here are some more Details:

Definition of Panel01

```
        // 
        // Panel01
        // 
        this.Panel01.Controls.Add(this.menuStrip1);
        this.Panel01.Controls.Add(this.Panel02);
        this.Panel01.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.Panel01.Name = "Panel01";
        this.Panel01.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1019, 1066);
        this.Panel01.TabIndex = 1;
```

Definition of Panel02

```
        // 
        // Panel02
        // 
        this.Panel02.AllowDrop = true;
        this.Panel02.AutoScroll = true;
        this.Panel02.Controls.Add(this.Stempel01);
        this.Panel02.Controls.Add(this.Datum01);
        this.Panel02.Controls.Add(this.Picture1);
        this.Panel02.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 25);
        this.Panel02.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
        this.Panel02.Name = "Panel02";
        this.Panel02.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1016, 1036);
        this.Panel02.TabIndex = 0;
```

Here, the Designer adds every Control (more than shown in the Screenshot).

Comment: thanks, I understand. I edited my post. hope, it's much more clear now

Comment: It looks like the some of the controls (those at the top) belong to Panel01 instead of Panel02. Move them back to Panel02 (select all, Cut then click inside Panel02 and Paste)

Comment: what you mean is the menuStrip1, which has to be in Panel01. I can then scroll the whole Window without scrolling the menuStrip out of side.

Comment: The MenuStrip should be child of the Form, the controls you see in the gray-ish area belong to either Panel01 or the Form itself. So, move them.

Comment: Jimi, you are right, the menustrip1 sould not be in a Panel. The Thing is that it has to be in a Panel to move everything at once (in my program, every form can be moved around)

Comment: Build UserControls if you need to *move things around*. Forms always *move around*. If you mean that you set the Parent on non-top level Forms, then build UserControls instead. I really don't know why you would parent the MenuStrip to a Panel, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

There really seemed to be a Problem with my Controls, not really connected to the Panels. Thanks again for everyone who commented.

I deleted every Control and replaced them one by one (and rebuilding the Program after every Control). After that, everything was where it supposed to be.

(Scrollpanels are really bad and I understood :) )

Comment: For people with the same problem: To check if the controls are proper connected you can use the document outline window (View -> Other Windows -> Document outline or CTRL+ALT+T while in designer view. It shows the actual structure of the form with it's subitems. If the single controls like buttons etc. aren't subitems of a panel you might have to drag and drop them on the right panel.

Comment: didnt know that, thank you! i will try this Right away

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED No. 2**

I figuered something else out which also leads to the bad behaviour:

My FormLoad sets the ActiveControl to a Control, which is during loading out of sight (window). After loading, I have a function which resizes all scrollable Panels. If I set the ActiveControl to something which is inside the Panel all the time, everything works nice.